# coldfusion: listContains and listFind

Tags: list, coldfusion

Whats the difference between `listContains()` and `listFind()` / `listFindNoCase()`?

They are all list functions, take the same parameters, and return the same result.

Comment: You must have been using [the wrong search phrase](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ColdFusion+listContains+vs+ListFind) ;-). The [first result](http://nm1m.blogspot.com/2010/09/listfind-vs-listcontains.html) contained a good explanation of the differences.

Comment: Yeah. I was using google not bing and must have been using bigger words like "difference between listfind and listcontains". I always wondered who these people are who use bing...

Comment: The ones coming up with the right answers :P? Though it made no difference for the terms ColdFusion listContains vs ListFind. The same link came up first in both engines. Even the more verbose expression ColdFusion difference between listfind and listcontains turned up a [very good article](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/06/know_your_list.html) as the second result!

Comment: An easy way to recall the difference is to think "Element" between "list" and the rest when you're trying to decide. So, "ListElementFind" and "ListElementContains".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`listContains` looks for the value anywhere in a string, so for example

```
<cfset list = '1,2,33,4,5' />
<cfdump var="#listContains(list,3)#">
```

Would return 3 because a 3 is found in the 3rd list item.

`listFind` looks for the value AS one of the list items.

```
<cfdump var="#listFind(list,3)#">
```

Returns 0 because 3 is not one of the list items.